# Can I use a pure pipe instead of the function expected by the binding?

Tags: angular

First of all, excuse the title. I lack the creativity for a better summary.

I am currently trying to get a grip on some performance issues we are seeing in our angular application. Although I am not at all an Angular expert, googling gave me some hints on what one might to improve. One mentioned thing is, try using (pure) pipes instead of function calls, because with a pipe Angular will take care of caching the result for a given input for you instead of executing the same code over and over again.
Now, let's image a component with the following markup:

```html
<some-table>
   <some-table-column *ngFor="let column of columns" name="{{column.name}}" [cellClass]="getCellClass">
      <ng-template let-row="row">
         <div>{{row.getCellValue(column)}}</div>
      </ng-template>
   </some-table-column>
</some-table>
```

Where the binding of `[cellClass]` is defined as `((data: any) => string | any)`

And then the following js:

```js
  getCellClass = (event: TableCellEvent): string => {
    console.count("getCellClass");
    if (event.column.prop === 'something') {
      return 'someClass'
    } else {
      return 'someOtherClass'
    }
  }
```

The function `getCellClass` is executed a lot, basically with every rendering initiated by every mouse movement.

Question:
Can I turn that function into a pipe accepting the `event` (or the value of `event.column.prop`) as an input?
If yes, how do a call that pipe?

Does that at all make sense? Is there another way to improve that (reduce the execution times of `getCellClass`)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is cellClass? can't you use a ngClass there? anyway, calling functions from your templates is not recommended (same issue with your getCellValue call). If your cellClass can be replaced with an [ngClass] you could simply do [ngClass]="{'someClass': column.prop === 'something'}..

Comment: @MikeOne As said, cellClass is `((data: any) => string | any)`. But even if it where an [ngClass] also there I might have the need to execute a more complex (but pure) logic which would not be easy to include in the markup.

Comment: The point here is that [cellClass] is an @Input for <some-table-column> and the only data it needs to operate seems to be the actual column. So I would simply expect [cellClass]="column" there and the 'some-table-column' would handle logic internally (in the component). So basically - it's a bit unclear what you want with it because your example is probably too theoretical.

Comment: @Bluddymarri This function will not affect performance much and what you mentioned is standard change detection, could it be that there is too many angular components in the table? I have faced a similar issue so putting it out there, Fix: virtualization or onpush change detection